# Setting up a remote Git repository via UNC name rather then https in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to figure out a simple Git workflow for setting up source control within our organization. I've read a number of articles on setting up a system using Github as the remote/origin but I want to set up the remote/origin on a UNC share on our network so that our code is stored internally to our organization. It seems that all the tutorials that I have seen only show the remote as being accessible via HTTPS.

Is it possible to use a UNC for the remote?

Comment: UNC paths might work using the file:// protocol (no windows here to verify), but definitively will work when being mounted as network drive (did this in the past).

Comment: Did you use the drive letter or the UNC syntax to made it work? Could you please post an example URI? THX!